# Invalid product id. Should be numeric value greater than 0

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, admin-controller

I have created custom button on Adminhtml Product edit page and it's showing fine. When I hit the button it's redirecting to Product List page and throwing Error.

> Error: Invalid product id. Should be numeric value greater than 0

[image]

for this I have written below code.

**root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml**

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">        
            <item name="custom" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">Custom</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">custom</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/custom</item>
            </item>
        </item>
```

**root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/adminhtml/Product/Edit/Custom.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

class Custom extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{
    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = ['edit'];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Product edit form
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager */
        $storeManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $store = $storeManager->getStore($storeId);
        $storeManager->setCurrentStore($store->getCode());
        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $product = $this->productBuilder->build($this->getRequest());

        file_put_contents('product.txt', print_r($productId,true), FILE_APPEND);

        if (($productId && !$product->getEntityId())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('This product doesn\'t exist.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/');
        } else if ($productId === 0) {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid product id. Should be numeric value greater than 0'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('catalog/*/');
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_edit_action', ['product' => $product]);

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->addHandle('catalog_product_' . $product->getTypeId());
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog::catalog_products');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Products'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($product->getName());

        if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->isSingleStoreMode()
            &&
            ($switchBlock = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('store_switcher'))
        ) {
            $switchBlock->setDefaultStoreName(__('Default Values'))
                ->setWebsiteIds($product->getWebsiteIds())
                ->setSwitchUrl(
                    $this->getUrl(
                        'catalog/*/*',
                        ['_current' => true, 'active_tab' => null, 'tab' => null, 'store' => null]
                    )
                );
        }

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.wysiwyg.js');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setStoreId($product->getStoreId());
        }

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

and button showing in product edit page.

[image]

When I hit the button it's redirecting to Product List page and throwing error. **Error: Invalid product id. Should be numeric value greater than 0**

When I hit the button I want to get the product id and after post back it's in same page no need to redirect list page.

Help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following code.

**VendorName=SR , ModuleName=StackExchange**

UI_Component form config **[SR/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom" xsi:type="string">SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Custom
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Button class **[SR/StackExchange/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/Custom.php]**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

class Custom extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        if($this->getProduct()->getId()) {
            $store = $this->context->getRequestParam('store');
            if(!isset($store)) {
                $store = 0;
            }

            $params = [
                'id' => $this->getProduct()->getId(),
                'store' => $store
            ];
            $customUrl = $this->getUrl('stackexchange/stackexchange/custom', $params);
            return [
                'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $customUrl),
                'class' => 'action-secondary',
                'sort_order' => 10
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Controller **[SR/StackExchange/Controller/Adminhtml/Stackexchange/Custom.php]**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Controller\Adminhtml\Stackexchange;

class Custom extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * Save constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

        $resultRedirect->setPath(
            'catalog/product/edit',
            ['id' => $productId, 'store' => $store,'_current' => true, 'set' => $product->getAttributeSetId()]
        );

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

And Admin router looks like

```
#SR/StackExchange/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="stackexchange" frontName="stackexchange">
            <module name="SR_StackExchange" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```